# influxdb query for 5 top cpu usage

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

I run a shared web hosting using CloudLinux.
From it, I can get a bunch of performence metric

So, my influxDB is :

measurement : lve

fields : CPU,EP,IO,IOPS,MEM,MEMPHY,NETI,NETO,NPROC,fEP,fMEM,fMEMPHY,fNPROC,lCPU,lCPUW,lEP,lIO,lIOPS,lMEM,lMEMPHY,lNETI,lNETO,lNPROC,nCPU

tags : xpool, host, user (where : xpool is xen-pool uid, host is hostname of cloudLinux, user is username of shared hosting)

data is gathered each 5 seconds

How is the query sentence to :

1. Select records from specific xpool+host , and
2. get 5 unique username that produce TOP CPU usage in 5 minute periode from it ?. 
   There is hundreds usaername but I want got top-5 only.

Note: Samething like example 4 of TOP() from https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/query_language/functions/#top, unless that expected results is:

```
name: h2o_feet
time                  top    location
----                  ---    --------
2015-08-18T00:00:00Z  8.12   coyote_creek
2015-08-18T00:54:00Z  2.054  santa_monica
```

Rather than :

```
name: h2o_feet
time                  top    location
----                  ---    --------
2015-08-18T00:48:00Z  7.11   coyote_creek
2015-08-18T00:54:00Z  6.982  coyote_creek
2015-08-18T00:54:00Z  2.054  santa_monica
2015-08-18T00:24:00Z  7.635  coyote_creek
2015-08-18T00:30:00Z  7.5    coyote_creek
2015-08-18T00:36:00Z  7.372  coyote_creek
2015-08-18T00:00:00Z  8.12   coyote_creek
2015-08-18T00:06:00Z  8.005  coyote_creek
2015-08-18T00:12:00Z  7.887  coyote_creek
```

Since '8.12' is the highest value of 'coyote_creek' and '2.054' is the highest value of 'santa_monica'

Sincerely

-bino-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a subquery could help, for example, this is from a database using telegraf:

```
SELECT top,host FROM (SELECT TOP(usage_user, 1) AS top, host from cpu WHERE time > now() -1m GROUP BY host)
```

It will output something like:

```
name: cpu
time                top                 host
----                ---                 ----
1527489800000000000 1.4937106918238994  1.host.tld
1527489808000000000 0.3933910306845004  2.host.tld
1527489810000000000 4.17981072555205    3.host.tld
1527489810000000000 0.8654602675059009  4.host.tld
```

The first query is:

```
SELECT TOP(usage_user, 1) AS top, host from cpu WHERE time > now() -1m GROUP BY host
```

Is using `TOP` to get only 1 item and using the field `usage_user`

Then to "pretty print" A subquery is used:

```
SELECT top,host FROM (...)
```